# CSS to be changed to be compatible with all the browsers

Tags: css

```
html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font: normal 14px/16px Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        background: #cbd2d8;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, 
                from(#c5ccd4), 
                color-stop(0.75, #c5ccd4), 
                color-stop(0.75, transparent), 
                to(transparent)); 
        -webkit-background-size: 5px 100%;
        background-size: 5px 100%;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    header.navigation-bar {
        position: relative;
        width: 10display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-pack:justify;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;0%;

        height: 45px;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#b2bbca), 
                color-stop(0.25, #a7b0c3),
                color-stop(0.5, #909cb3), 
                color-stop(0.5, #8593ac), 
                color-stop(0.75, #7c8ba5),
                to(#73839f)); 
        border-top: 1px solid #cdd5df;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2d3642; 
    }
    header.navigation-bar.black {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-pack:justify;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 45px;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#636363), 
                color-stop(0.25, #424242),
                color-stop(0.5, #202020), 
                color-stop(0.5, #000000)); 
        border-top: 1px solid #858585;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #858585; 
    }
    h1 {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        font: bold 20px/32px Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #fff;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #fff;
        color: #666;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Bordered Button Styles */
    .button.bordered {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #9aa5bb, 0 -1px 1px #8e96a5; 
        border: solid 1px #54617d;
        border-color: #484e59 #54617d #4c5c7a #54617d; 
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 28px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#92a1bf), 
                color-stop(0.25, #798aad),
                color-stop(0.5, #6276a0), 
                color-stop(0.5, #556a97), 
                color-stop(0.75, #566c98),
                to(#546993)); 
        color: #fff;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    .button.bordered:hover, .button.bordered.touched {
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#7d88a5), 
                color-stop(0.25, #58698c),
                color-stop(0.5, #3a4e78), 
                color-stop(0.5, #253c6a), 
                color-stop(0.75, #273f6d),
                to(#273f6d));
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }
    /* End Bordered Button Styles */

    /* Back Bordered Button Styles */
    .button.bordered.back {
        padding: 0px 7px 0px 3px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .button.bordered.back > span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .button.bordered.back > span.pointer {
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                from(#92a1bf), 
                color-stop(0.3, #798aad),
                color-stop(0.51, #6276a0), 
                color-stop(0.51, #556a97), 
                color-stop(0.75, #566c98),
                to(#546993)); 
        border-left: solid 1px #484e59;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #9aa5bb;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        height: 23.5px;
        width: 23.5px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-mask-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, 
                from(#000000), 
                color-stop(0.5,#000000), 
                color-stop(0.5, transparent), 
                to(transparent));
        position: absolute;
        left: -9px;
        top: 2.5px;
        -webkit-background-clip: content;
    }
    .button.bordered.back:hover > span.pointer, .button.bordered.back.touched > span.pointer {
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                from(#7d88a5), 
                color-stop(0.3, #58698c),
                color-stop(0.51, #3a4e78), 
                color-stop(0.51, #253c6a), 
                color-stop(0.75, #273f6d),
                to(#273f6d)); 
    }

    /* End Back Bordered Button Styles */

    /* Next Bordered Button Styles */
    .button.bordered.next {
        padding: 0px 3px 0px 7px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .button.bordered.next > span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .button.bordered.next > span.pointer {
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                from(#92a1bf), 
                color-stop(0.3, #798aad),
                color-stop(0.51, #6276a0), 
                color-stop(0.51, #556a97), 
                color-stop(0.75, #566c98),
                to(#546993)); 
        border-right: solid 1px #9aa5bb;
        border-top: solid 1px #484e59;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;         
        height: 23.5px;
        width: 23.5px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-mask-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left bottom, 
                from(#000000), 
                color-stop(0.5,#000000), 
                color-stop(0.5, transparent), 
                to(transparent));
        position: absolute;
        right: -9px;
        top: 2.5px;
        -webkit-background-clip: content;
    }
    .button.bordered.next:hover > span.pointer, .button.bordered.next.touched > span.pointer {
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                from(#7d88a5), 
                color-stop(0.3, #58698c),
                color-stop(0.51, #3a4e78), 
                color-stop(0.51, #253c6a), 
                color-stop(0.75, #273f6d),
                to(#273f6d)); 
    }
    /* End Next Bordered Button Styles */

    header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #242424, 0 -1px 1px #323232; 
        border: solid 1px #54617d;
        border-color: #404040 #262626 #404040 #262626; 
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#838383), 
                color-stop(0.5, #444444), 
                color-stop(0.5, #303030), 
                to(#333333)); 
    }
    header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered.back > span.pointer {
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                color-stop(0.05, #838383), 
                color-stop(0.5, #444444), 
                color-stop(0.5, #303030), 
                color-stop(0.98, #333333)); 
        border-left: solid 1px #262626;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #404040;
        top: 2.35px;
    }

    header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered.next > span.pointer {
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                color-stop(0.05, #838383), 
                color-stop(0.5, #444444), 
                color-stop(0.5, #303030), 
                color-stop(0.98, #333333)); 
        border-right: solid 1px #404040;
        border-top: solid 1px #262626;
        top: 2.35px;
    }
    header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered:hover, header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered.touched {
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                from(#4286f5), 
                color-stop(0.5, #4286f5),
                color-stop(0.5, #194fdb),
                to(#194fdb));
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }
    header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered.back:hover > span.pointer, header.navigation-bar.black > .button.back.touched > span.pointer, header.navigation-bar.black > .button.bordered.next:hover > span.pointer, header.navigation-bar.black > .button.next.touched > span.pointer {
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
                from(#4286f5), 
                color-stop(0.5, #4286f5),
                color-stop(0.5, #194fdb),
                to(#194fdb));
    }
```

Hi,
This is the css for a header and its button. it is styled to be like iPhone header and button. However, it only works in chrome or safari (webkit based browsers).I want this code to converted for it to work in mozilla and IE also..please help

Comment: We don't code for you.... If you get stuck with something in particular explain it here, but don't ask us to make all your worK...

Comment: So in short, you want us to do your work for you... If you want help, you'll need to narrow it down, find the exact source of the problem, and prove that you've at least tried *something* by yourself.

Comment: show us your `html`. and create [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/).com with your `html&css` we will be able to start with it

Comment: Its not surprising that it doesn't work, most of the attributes are for webkit only hence "-webkit" you need to add all of the alternatives for different browsers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixr (http://prefixr.com/) is a free tool that converts your CSS into proper cross-browser CSS. It's not perfect and won't make your CSS perfectly rendered in every browser, but it should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it only works for webkit because you are only referencing webkit browsers with your background code:

```
-webkit-gradient
```

What you need to do is address the other browsers using:

```
-moz-linear-gradient
linear-gradient
etc etc....
```

**Just for reference try these out for creating proper gradients / CSS3 stuff:**

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

http://css3generator.com/

---

**EDIT:** Don't forget you also need to address your other '-webkit' only selectors like -webkit-box-* but to be honest I don't think it's a good idea to use the box-* selectors for simple menu / navigation items. Better to use:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>nav element 1...</li>
    <li>nav element 2...</li>
</ul>
```

Then just style your html with the relevant CSS (hint, look at either the 'float' method or inline-block) as this will save lots of CSS code lines.